# Arcade expressions for diplay in Collector

Tags: esri

I am working to create a 'Number of Days Open' indicator using ESRI's Collector app. It needs to display the Maximum and Mean values for the number of days a request has been open. However, the table only provides the Date that a request was opened. The number of days a request has been open can be determined using the DateDiff function, but I am having trouble with the full table of values approx. 20,000.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var today = Now();
var startdate = $datapoint["created_at"];
var numberdays = DateDiff (today, startdate, 'days');
var Big = Max(numberdays);
var Middle = Mean(numberdays);




return {
    textColor:'',
    backgroundColor:'',
    topText:'Avg: ' + Middle,
    topTextColor: '',
    topTextOutlineColor: '',
    topTextMaxSize: 'medium',
    middleText: 'Max: '+ Big,
    middleTextColor: '',
    middleTextOutlineColor: '',
    middleTextMaxSize: 'medium',
}
```